# How to change your ssh & filezilla password on ovh?

Tags: ssh, filezilla

How do you change your ssh password. Can I change it through the ovh control panel or something? Also how do I change my filezilla password?

Comment: -1 for low detail, and showing 0 research effort. OVH's panel makes it incredibly easy last I checked. Your "FileZilla" password if using SFTP is the same as your SSH password.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I change my OVH ssh password?

> Upon delivery of your server (under Redhat), you receive an email
>   summary containing two passwords. The first is used for the root
>   account via SSH and webmin, the second for MySQL.
>
> Upon delivery, the passwords for SSH and webmin are synchronised
>   perfectly but you can use a different password to log in as root in
>   SSH than from the one you use to log on as root through webmin.
>   Similarly, you may need for different reasons to modify any of these
>   passwords.
>
> **SSH Access**
>
> To change the root password that you use to log into SSH, you must be
>   logged in and use the SSH command passwd. The system then asks for the
>   new password:
>
> ```
> [root@julien /]# passwd
> New password:
> Retype new password:
> passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully
> ```
>
> The last line indicates when the password has been changed
>   successfully. These changes do not affect the root password for
>   webmin. Similarly, when you are logged in as root through SSH, you can
>   change the password of any user of the server. This affects the
>   password used by that user to log into SSH and / or FTP. The command
>   is as follows (user represents the user's login):
>
> ```
> [root@julien /]# passwd user
> ```

Source [What are the different passwords on my server? How to edit?](http://help.ovh.co.uk/DedicatedServerPassword)